# Updating columns in heroku production vs local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails (v 4.2.0) app this is deployed to Heroku, with a PostgresQL database.

I have a number of objects in my db that I populate with my seeds.rb file:

```
Item.create([
  {name: "Kale", type: "veggie"},
  {name: "Apple", type: "fruit"},
  {name: "MF Kombucha", type: "drink"},
  {name: "Cider", type: "drink"},
  {name: "Carrot", type: "veggie"}
  ])
```

I need to add a column to my `items` table, `:price`:

`rails g migration AddPriceToItems`

```
class AddPriceToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :items, :price, :integer
  end
end
```

I then update my seeds file:

```
Item.create([
  {name: "Kale", type: "veggie", price: 2},
  {name: "Apple", type: "fruit", price: 1},
  {name: "MF Kombucha", type: "drink", price: 10000},
  {name: "Cider", type: "drink", price: 2},
  {name: "Carrot", type: "veggie", price: 1}
  ])
```

Locally, this is totally fine. I sync this new data with other data in the seeds file:

`rake db:drop`

`rake db:create`

`rake db:migrate`

`rake db:seed`

However, in production, the database now has user entered data. Dropping the database would mean dropping the user data.

Is there a way to sync the new seeds file with the production database, without having to drop the database? Ideally, this would be more efficient than `heroku run rails c` and manually editing all the info in my console.

Comment: You need to rewrite your seeds file so that it can run against existing data. There is no magic way of doing this.

Comment: running `heroku rake db:migrate` will update your schema with the new price column in the items table. It shouldn't affect the users table unless there's some sort of association between prices and users you didn't mention.

Comment: by the way, you can try something similar in development by adding a column to a table, running just `rake db:migrate` to update the schema, and then confirm that the users you created are still there in development.

Comment: Is `Item#name` unique or is there some other way to uniquely identifier your seeded data? Does your seeds file really only create five `Item`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [**`find_or_create_by`**](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by). Just create another migration and loop over the seeds. As for heroku this will be a safer way to change seeds without losing production data.

```
class AddPriceToItemSeeds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    items= [
      {name: "Kale", type: "veggie", price: 2},
      {name: "Apple", type: "fruit", price: 1},
      {name: "MF Kombucha", type: "drink", price: 10000},
      {name: "Cider", type: "drink", price: 2},
      {name: "Carrot", type: "veggie", price: 1}
    ]
    items.each do |item|
      Item.find_or_create_by(name: item[:name], type: item[:type]) do |record|
        record.price= item[:price]
      end
    end
  end
end
```